# How increment student roll numbers continuously

Tags: python, tkinter, increment

I am python beginner. I am building small school system using python and sqlite3. I want to record student registration. I created a student file in python. One of the widgets which should be filled is student roll numbers. I want it to be automatically incremented. I also want the next new roll number to be shown in the widget entry.

I have used below codes which i have got from this website. It helped me to solve half the problem. But every time I close and open the form, it starts the roll number from 0 rather than continuing next roll numbers.
Really i would appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *

def clicked():
    rollNo.set(rollNo.get()+1)

window = Tk()
window.title("Programme")
window.geometry('350x250')

rollNo = IntVar()

label = Label(window, textvariable=rollNo).grid(column=0,row=0)

button = Button(window, text="Push Me", command=clicked).grid(column=1, 
row=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can create class that inherits from enum that has auto() function for increment. Also consider creating one post per question as this has nothing to do with showing that in GUI; showing things in GUI is completely separate problem.

Comment: Hello if you use an SQL base maybe you can stock the value of the roll in the database and read it every time you open the form. Have a nice day

Comment: C'mon @CharlesMarcucci - its Python it has way to store class variable and do count - you can implement own counter or inherit from Enum class, but you don't need sql db for that!

Comment: He wants to register the student registration, if he wants to remember all the connexion I think the DB is better. May be I doesn't understand correctly the question

Comment: How can i start roll numbers from 1?

Comment: @Siciid when creating the intvar, pass 1 as the value attribute. Then the roll numbers will be starting from 1. `IntVar(value=1)`

Comment: I used IntVar(value=1) but once i close and open again the program, it starts the roll number from 1. What could i do?

Comment: Since you mentions that `sqlite3` is used and I think it is used to store student registration data including the *student roll number*.  So why don't you get the next student roll number (*it really depends on how you store those information*) from the `sqlite3` db when the program starts?

Answer (score 3):

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Programme")
window.geometry('350x250')
rollNo = IntVar()

try : 
    a = open('rolls.txt','r')
    num_roll = a.readlines()
    rollNo.set(int(num_roll[-1]))
    a = open('rolls.txt','w')

except:
    a = open('rolls.txt','w')

def clicked():
    a.write(str(rollNo.get()+1)+'\n')
    rollNo.set(rollNo.get()+1)





label = Label(window, textvariable=rollNo).grid(column=0,row=0)

button = Button(window, text="Push Me", command=clicked).grid(column=1, 
row=2)


window.mainloop()
```